# Finding a compact and positively invariant set

Tags: dynamical-systems, polar-coordinates, set-invariance

I have the system:
$$\begin{cases}\dot{x}=-x-xy\\\\
\dot{y}=x-\frac{1}{4}y+x^2-y^3\end{cases}$$
I have been tasked to find, using the Poincare-Bendixson Theorem, that the ω-limit set of any point
p ∈ $\mathbb{R}^2$ is the origin.

So far I've found, with a good level of confidence (0,0) is the only equilibrium, is hyperbolic and is asymptotically stable. Furthermore, I've found that there is no periodic orbit lying in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

However heres where I'm unsure: I know to apply P-B Theorem I need to find a compact and positively invariant set however I've never done so before. A similar example in the notes immediately seeks to evaluate $\frac{1}{2}$$\frac{d}{dt}$$(x^2+y^2)$, how come we do this? My intuition tells me that it should be to do with polar coordinates however I'm unsure. Following this I feel as I've found there is no periodic orbit in this system and that (0,0) is the only equilibrium point this implies ω(p) is an equilibrium point for any p ∈ $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)=-x^2 + x y - y^2/4 - y^4
$$
and the matrix in the quadratic form
$$
-x^2 + x y - y^2/4=\begin{pmatrix}x& y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-1 & 1/2 \\ 1/2 &-1/4\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x\\ y\end{pmatrix}
$$
has eigenvalues $-5/4$ and $0$, the latter with eigenvector $(1/2,1)$. This means that $$-x^2 + x y - y^2/4\le0$$ with equality if and only if $y=2x$. Therefore,
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)< - y^4
$$
for $y\ne 2x$, and
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)\le - y^4
$$
for $y= 2x$. Summing up we have
$$
\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(x^2+y^2)<0
$$
outside the origin.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. One more question, how come we immediately seek to find this derivative? I'm unsure on why we do this.

Comment: @murpw2011 It measures the distance to the origin. But many times it doesn't work, and it can even be a matter of trial and error. Accepting my answer would be appreciated, in case it is helpful.